# Fill multi dimension array with plain text in Powershell

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array, plaintext, emc

I am working on a Powershell script to monitor a SAN.
I successfully extracted a text file containing all the values from the system in Powershell with this code:

```
& "NaviSecCli.exe" -user xxxx -password xxxx -h host -f "C:\LUNstate.txt" lun -list
$Path = "C:\LUNstate.txt"
$Text = "Capacity \(GBs\)"
$Name = "^Name"
Get-Content $Path | Select-String -pattern $Text,$Name
```

This generates the following output:

```
Name:  TEST-DATASTORE-1
User Capacity (GBs):  1536.000
Consumed Capacity (GBs):  955.112
Name:  CV Snapshot Mountpoint
User Capacity (GBs):  1024.000
Consumed Capacity (GBs):  955.112
```

Now I can split the values through the colon, by putting the output into a variable:

```
$LUNArray = Get-Content $Path | Select-String -pattern $Text,$Name
$LUNArray | foreach {
    $LUNArray = $_ -split ':  '
    Write-Host $LUNArray[0]
    Write-Host $LUNArray[1]
}
```

The only interesting data is stored in $LUNArray[1], so I can just leave out Write-Host $LUNArray[0] which gives me the following output:

```
TEST-DATASTORE-1
1536.000
955.112
CV Snapshot Mountpoint
1024.000
955.112
```

Now the tricky part, I would like to put the data into a multi dimensional array. So I would get the following array layout:

```
LUN                     Usercap    ConsCap
TEST-DATASTORE-1        1536.000   955.112
CV Snapshot Mountpoint  1024.000   955.112
```

---

The input file looks like this:

```
LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER 201
Name:  TEST-DATASTORE-1
UID:  60:06:E4:E3:11:50:E4:E3:11:20:A4:D0:C6:E4:E3:11
Current Owner:  SP B
Default Owner:  SP B
Allocation Owner:  SP B
User Capacity (Blocks):  3221225472
User Capacity (GBs):  1536.000
Consumed Capacity (Blocks):  2005641216
Consumed Capacity (GBs):  956.364
Pool Name:  Pool HB Hasselt
Raid Type:  Mixed
Offset:  0
Auto-Assign Enabled:  DISABLED
Auto-Trespass Enabled:  DISABLED
Current State:  Ready
Status:  OK(0x0)
Is Faulted:  false
Is Transitioning:  false
Current Operation:  None
Current Operation State:  N/A
Current Operation Status:  N/A
Current Operation Percent Completed:  0
Is Pool LUN:  Yes
Is Thin LUN:  Yes
Is Private:  No
Is Compressed:  No
Tiering Policy:  Lowest Available
Initial Tier:  Lowest Available
Tier Distribution:  
Capacity:  100.00%

LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER 63920
Name:  CV Snapshot Mountpoint
UID:  60:50:38:00:14:50:38:00:C6:64:50:38:00:50:38:00
Current Owner:  SP B
Default Owner:  SP B
Allocation Owner:  SP B
User Capacity (Blocks):  2147483648
User Capacity (GBs):  1024.000
Consumed Capacity (Blocks):  2005641216
Consumed Capacity (GBs):  956.364
Pool Name:  Pool HB Hasselt
Raid Type:  Mixed
Offset:  0
Auto-Assign Enabled:  DISABLED
Auto-Trespass Enabled:  DISABLED
Current State:  Ready
Status:  OK(0x0)
Is Faulted:  false
Is Transitioning:  false
Current Operation:  None
Current Operation State:  N/A
Current Operation Status:  N/A
Current Operation Percent Completed:  0
Is Pool LUN:  Yes
Is Thin LUN:  Yes
Is Private:  No
Is Compressed:  No
Tiering Policy:  Lowest Available
Initial Tier:  Lowest Available
Tier Distribution:  
Capacity:  100.00%

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a list of custom objects, like this:

```
& "NaviSecCli.exe" -user xxxx -password xxxx -h host -f "C:\LUNstate.txt" lun -list

$datafile = 'C:\LUNstate.txt'
$pattern  = 'Name:\s+(.*)[\s\S]+(User Capacity).*?:\s+(.*)\s+(Consumed Capacity).*?:\s+(.*)'

$LUNArray = (Get-Content $datafile | Out-String) -split '\r\n(\r\n)+' |
  Select-String $pattern -AllMatches |
  Select-Object -Expand Matches |
  % {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
      'LUN'              = $_.Groups[1].Value
      $_.Groups[2].Value = $_.Groups[3].Value
      $_.Groups[4].Value = $_.Groups[5].Value
    }
  }
```

The data can be displayed for instance like this:

```
"{0}: {1}" -f $LUNArray[1].LUN, $LUNArray[1].'Consumed Capacity'
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not seem to do the trick. How to display the separate items of the array so I can use them for further processing?

Comment: @KingT See updated answer. You would've gotten this much earlier had you added the sample input data to your question right away. Surprising as it may seem, when parsing data, the actual structure of the data *does* matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filePath = 'absolute path'
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($filePath)
[regex]::Matches(
    $content,
    '(?x)
        Name: [ ]* ([^\n]+)  #  name
        \n User [ ] (Capacity) [^:]+: [ ]* ([^\n]+) # capacity 
        \n Consumed [ ] \2  [^:]+:[ ]* ([^\n]+)' # Consumed
    ) | 
    ForEach-Object {

              $LUN = $_.groups[1].value
              $Usercap = $_.groups[3].value
              $ConsCap = $_.groups[4].value
          # process $Lun, $Usercap and $ConsCap

    }
```